# <table>-like UI element for wxHaskell/wxWidgets

Tags: user-interface, haskell, html-table, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

I am working on writing a GUI in Haskell (and Ur/Web, but that is another story), and have several development branches using different libraries and approaches that I am working on contemporaneously. In trying to migrate some of the code I had from browser-backed UI libraries with HTML elements (threepenny-gui, to be precise) to native GUI applets using a WX graphical backend (wxHaskell, reactive-banana), I encountered some trouble figuring out how to migrate some code I had that was based on constructing a `<table>` element to an equivalent wxWidgets construct. It seemed to me that there was no easy way to implement such a thing on my own, and no native equivalent. I am looking for implementation suggestions, pointers to extant implementations, suitable alternatives, and so forth. I can provide more in-depth specifics of the design I am looking for, should that be required.

The html table is merely used for aligning and displaying data, where one cell in every row is a reactive control, and the number of rows displayed at any given time can also vary reactively.

Answer (score 2):

HTML table can contain just about anything in its cells so it's too rich to be represented by any native control. It's really hard to make a recommendation without knowing what exactly you have in the table, but the different possibilities are:

- `wxHtmlWindow`: this can be used to reuse your HTML provided it's simple enough (HTML4 basically) and you can embed native controls into it if needed.
- `wxGrid`: this is the most flexible widget, but it's not native.
- `wxDataViewCtrl`: this is native control under GTK and OS X (but not MSW where you'd need to use `wxListCtrl` for 100% native approach) but it's pretty limited compared to either of the above solutions.

Comment: In my widget library building, I am trying to keep things as general as possible, but the particular application I have in mind would contain only text and small icons, in addition to the reactive widget I mentioned. That widget is in turn an elevated button that snapshots a time-varying value at click-time.

Comment: This looks doable with wxDVC but you'd have to write a custom renderer for the widget.

Comment: I am used to writing custom renderers for my widgets. Do you have any examples/guides that might help me implement the DVC table? I don't have a lot of familiarity with the library.

Comment: As usual, look at the [sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/WX_3_0_2/samples/dataview/dataview.cpp)

Comment: this is interesting, but not especially useful to me as it stands (I may be missing something though), as wxHaskell doesn't seem to implement this. I will probably try to go about writing a custom widget for this purpose.